# Plotting contour and wireframe plots with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have to plot contour and wireframe plots for function [image: formula] . This is the code I have so far:

```py
# Number of uniformly ditributed random numbers
n = 2000

def func_vec(x1s, x2s):
    return x1s * x1s + 4 * x2s * x2s

np.random.seed()
x1s = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n)
x2s = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n)
ys = func_vec(x1s, x2s)

fig = plt.figure()

# Scatter
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax1.scatter(x1s, x2s, color = 'g', s = 2, edgecolor = 'none')
ax1.set_ylim([-1,1])
ax1.set_xlim([-1,1])

# Contour
ax1.contour(x2s, x1s, ys[np.newaxis,:].repeat(n, axis = 0))

# 3D visualization
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection = '3d')
X = x1s
Y = x2s
Z = ys
ax2.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride = 1, cstride = 1)

plt.show()
```

What I don't understand is how do `contour()` and `plot_firewrame()` actually work? Can somebody please be so kind and explain this to me (in the context of specified function)? Furthermore, how should I specify X, Y and Z?

This is how the plot looks now:
[image]

and this is how it should look like (scatter above works OK):
[image]

Comment: Those function expect structure in the ordering of the points.  The wireframe code draws lines between the 4-connected neighbors, hence why you get a bird's nest.

Comment: Thanks, `griddata()` and `meshgrid()` did the job!

Comment: Can you post an answer explaining what you did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code that will produce the correct plots. Anyone struggling with this, should find the code pretty much self-explanatory:

```py
# Number of uniformly ditributed random numbers
n = 2000

def func_vec(x1s, x2s):
    return x1s * x1s + 4 * x2s * x2s

np.random.seed()
x1s = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n)
x2s = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n)
ys = func_vec(x1s, x2s)

fig = plt.figure(22)

# Scatter
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax1.scatter(x1s, x2s, color = 'g', s = 2, edgecolor = 'none')
ax1.set_ylim([-1,1])
ax1.set_xlim([-1,1])

# Contour
xi = np.linspace(-1,1,20)
yi = np.linspace(-1,1,20)
zi = griddata((x2s, x1s), ys, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method = 'cubic')
ax1.contour(xi, yi, zi, 6, linewidths = 1, colors = ('#0000ff', '#0099ff', '#009999', '#999900', '#ff9900', '#ff0000'))

# 3D visualization
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection = '3d')
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
ax2.plot_wireframe(X, Y, zi, rstride = 1, cstride = 1)
ax2.view_init(28, -144) 

plt.show()
```

Comment: how can I get some more solid-color schemes for contour than just colored-lines !?

Comment: @diffracteD Use `contourf`.

Comment: Is it possible to do it backward ? I mean from a 3D dataset to generate a surface-fit model and then get the equation of the fitted-surface.. ??